# Transaction expiration time

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio.token

Is it possible to configure or change the

```
"expiration": "2018-06-26T14:33:24",
```

time? Currently its 30 seconds on my local node after I generate a transaction so I do not get time to execute it and it expires.

This is an example of transaction:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "expiration": "2018-12-02T14:33:24",
    "ref_block_num": 65294,
    "ref_block_prefix": 4173364468,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "lucaszhang15",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": "50029ba67d6c908e10029ba67d6c908ee80300000000000004454f53000000000474657374"
      }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": []
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by modifying `max-transaction-time = 30` in config.ini according to your own preferred time. If you push transaction by cleos then i don't think it will get expires in 30 seconds as per my experience in eosio.